# Issue with reaching second level of menu after hovering on first level

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navigation

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li id="homebutton"> <a href="#">Home </a></li>
  <li id="servicebutton"> <a href="#" >Services </a></li>
  <li id="packagebutton"> <a href="#" >Packages </a></li>
  <li id="spabutton"> <a href="#">The spa </a></li>
  <li id="productbutton"> <a href="#">Product </a></li>
  <li id="mebutton"> <a href="#">About Me </a></li>
  <li id="contactbutton"> <a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              <div class="submenu">
              <div id="services_menu" class="active">
              <ul>
                <li>Services1</li>
                <li>Services2</li>
                <li>Services3</li>
                <li>Services4</li>
                <li>Services5</li>
              </ul>
              </div>
              <div id="packages_menu">
              <ul>
                <li>Packages1</li>
                <li>Packages2</li>
                <li>Packages3</li>
                <li>Packages4</li>
                <li>Packages5</li>
              </ul>
              </div>    
              </div>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.main_menu  {list-style-type: none; text-align: center;background-color:yellow;}
ul.main_menu li  {margin-left: 20px; display: inline; background-color:red;}
ul.main_menu li a  {text-decoration: none;color: white;}
.submenu  {height: 20px;width: 100%;}
#services_menu  {display: none;margin-top: 10px;}
#services_menu ul {list-style-type: none; text-align: center;}
#services_menu ul li  {margin-left: 20px; display: inline;}
#service_menu ul li a  {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
#packages_menu  {display: none; margin-top: 10px;}
#packages_menu ul {list-style-type: none; text-align: center;}
#packages_menu ul li  {margin-left: 20px; display: inline;}
#packages_menu ul li a  {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
.active {display: block!important;}
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery("#packagebutton").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery('#services_menu').removeClass( "active" );
            jQuery('#packages_menu').addClass("active");
        }, 
        function () {
            jQuery('#packages_menu').removeClass("active");
            jQuery('#services_menu').addClass( "active" );
        }
);
```

I am creating a navigation in this when I hover on level one it appears but after that when I move mouse pointer to level two, second level disappear.

What should be the change in code or in html that helps me to fix this issue?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7VpyY/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i updated your script please see this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#packagebutton").mouseenter(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('#services_menu').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#packages_menu').addClass("active");
    }
  });
  $("#packagebutton").mouseleave(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('#services_menu').addClass("active");
        $('#packages_menu').removeClass("active");
    }
  });
})
```

The demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/7VpyY/14/

Comment: but when I move mouse pointer away from Packages tab it should be back to services tab.

Comment: mins that you do not want drop down for service ? @AryaMehta

Comment: I mean when I move mouse pointer away from Packages tab,  `#services_menu ` should activated again

Comment: ok #service_menu always activated but when you mouseover on #package_menu  '#service_menu' deactivet and #package_menu  activate @AryaMehta

Comment: i upadated my code and jsfiddle link please see this in jsfiddle i also change css and html  @AryaMehta

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
jQuery("#packagebutton").hover(
function () {
    jQuery('#services_menu').removeClass( "active" );
    jQuery('#packages_menu').addClass("active");
},function(){
    jQuery('#services_menu').addClass( "active" );
    jQuery('#packages_menu').removeClass("active");
    });

jQuery("#servicebutton").hover(
function () {
    jQuery('#packages_menu').removeClass( "active" );
    jQuery('#services_menu').addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: but when I move mouse pointer away from Packages tab it should be back to services tab.